# How to combine an array of JS objects with an existing immutable JS ordered map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

In my application I asynchronously fetch results and store them in the Redux store as an Immutable JS ordered map. I would like to append to this ordered map when I receive a new array of JS objects from the ajax call. Somehow, I do not think converting the OrderedMap to JS and then concatenating the results is the best performance-wise way to merge new JS objects into the OrderedMap. And, I am sure this is a common problem but I cannot find this question answered.

Comment: how many items are we talking? If it's not in the 1000s and/or not causing any noticeable problems I wouldn't worry about prematurely optimising.

Comment: For now I just converted JS results to an OrderedMap and then merge the two OrderedMaps. I can't think of a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way (`merge` can take an array of key-value pairs):

```
const keyValuePairsArray = newItemsArray.map(item => [getKey(item), item]);

const myNewMap = myExistingMap.merge(keyValuePairsArray);
```

---

Another option would be to create an object instead of a key-value pairs array, but I think it's uglier:

```
const newItemsPojo = newItemsArray.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[getKey(item)] = item;
    return obj;
}, {});

const myNewMap = myExistingMap.merge(newItemsPojo);
```

---

The high-performance option is to use `withMutations` (this is what `merge` does under the hood), but I think it makes for the least-readable code, it isn't really much faster, and there are special rules about how to use `withMutations`:

```
const myNewMap = myExistingMap.withMutations(existing => {

    const newMap = existing;

    newItemsArray.forEach(item => {
        newMap.set(getKey(item), item);
    });

    return newMap;
});
```